# Angular on broadcast or when view is loaded?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple service that get's the gps-position of the device and broadcasts it:

There is also a default location.

```
service('currentPosition', function($rootScope){
        //default current position
        var myLocation = {lat: 59.3325800, long: 18.0649000}
        $rootScope.$broadcast('location', myLocation)

        if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                myLocation.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                myLocation.long = position.coords.longitude;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('location', myLocation)
            });
        }
        return{
            getMyLocation: function(){
                return myLocation;
            }
        }
    }).
```

In several views of my application, I want to add a listener for changes to the location. I also want to get the value when the view is loaded. I keep on writing something like:

```
$scope.myLocation = currentPosition.getMyLocation();
$scope.$on('location', function(scope,myLocation){
    $scope.myLocation = myLocation;
});
```

In several of my controllers and directives. Is there a better way to do this? For example by catching previously broadcasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are passing a reference to the `myLocation` object from your service to `$scope.myLocation` in your controller, they are working with the same object and you don't need to use $broadcast (or any other notification system for that matter) to get the updates.

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/PU3HyCx9YZybeADmv13I?p=preview

The service will first log the updated `myLocation` object, then after a small delay, the controller will log its `myLocation` object.

You will notice that both log the updated object.

The problem in this case is that the ui isn't updated. This is because the callback from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` happens "outside of Angular's world", which means the $digest loop will not be triggered and changes will not be reflected in the DOM.

From the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

In your case:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      myLocation.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      myLocation.long = position.coords.longitude;
    });
  });
}
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/hsN5xIPgtTDahyvpti0E?p=preview